# php preg_replace problem

Tags: php

```
$strSubject= preg_replace('/\b'.$strWord.'\b/i', '<b>'.$strWord.'</b>', $strSubject);
```

above code works in php 5.2.6 but not working in php 5.2.9 and get " warning,unknow modifer....." error. please help

Comment: What is in strWord? `var_dump($strWord);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a meta character unescaped in `$strWord`. Try this...

```
$strSubject= preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($strWord, '/').'\b/i', '<b>'.$strWord.'</b>', $strSubject);
```

Also, you could just use this :)

```
$strSubject = preg_replace('/\b('.preg_quote($strWord, '/').')\b/i', '<b>$1</b>', $strSubject);
```

Comment: @Weiqiu No worries, feel free to give me the big green tick :)